# How to generate all valid numeric expressions?

Tags: python, algorithm

Assume I have operators:  'add' 'sub' 'mul' 'div'(these have two parameters) and 'ifelse'(this should have three parameters)

And some variables: a, b, c, d

And some constants: 1,2,3,4

how can i generate all valid expressions on a given depth n?(time sensitive)

ps. valid expression, for example:  div(sub(add(a, b), 3), div(a, b)) is valid, and its depth is 3.

Comment: you can use recursion.

Comment: thx, could you give me some tips? i search online for the whole morning, but didnt find doc or blog which are friendly for a rockie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
import itertools as it
params = {'add':2, 'mul':2, 'sub':2, 'div':2, 'ifelse':3}
def get_exp(d, f = None):
  if d:
    for i in (params if not f else [f]):
       for k in it.product(*([[*range(1, 5), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', *params]]*params[i])):
          for l in it.product(*[[a] if a not in params else get_exp(d-1, a) for a in k]):
              yield f'{i}({", ".join(map(str, l))})'

stream = get_exp(3)
for _ in range(100):
   print(next(stream))
```